# I think my question has been closed unfairly

Tags: support

My question was:

"Is it true that using different sized RAM's will not lead to a better performance in 2020 laptops"

I've edited the question, but there seems to be some type of bot which immediately stops me from asking any questions, ever again.

See the edited version below which was made enormously more concise
On a side note: It might be helpful if tips were given on how to improve questions, since the present tips are rather vague, something which the site rules themselves...oppose.

=============BoQ=======================

Specifically, I am using DDR4 SoDIMM 8GB now, in a *Legion 5 17ACH6H*. Will adding 4GB RAM, lead to a **better** performance, the **same** performance, or éven a **worse** performance? Is my assumption that the more RAM, the merrier, a simplistic one?

*Follow up:* Is there a difference in outcomes with regards to **gaming**, or **non 4K video editing**, or having **100 browser tabs open**? I can imagine that going from 8GB to 12GB might improve 'open browser tabs' but perhaps not gaming performance.

PS

- I wanna stress **explicitly** that this question is NOT a homework assignment (since that a favorite reason given in case of mod abuse) nor is it seeking brand comparisons.
- Yes, I know it is possible to use different sized RAM, several mobo's support it. This is NOT my question.
- the other, nót-similar questions on this subject were 7 years old, so this can be viewed as an upgrade of sorts, looking at what has changed in the last 5-7 years.

=============EoQ=======================

Answer (score 2):

#### I've edited the question

That has put your question in the reopen queue where users with the appropriate privilege can vote if they think it should be reopened or not.

#### There seems to be some type of bot which immediately stops me from asking any questions, ever again

You have been automatically "blocked from asking" because of the poor quality of your questions. This is automated and cannot be overridden.

You have asked 43 questions but the aggregate score is -6 (including your deleted questions).

Please see the help center article [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: The question must have been deleted. I can’t find any recent question the author has submitted.